# How to blit a random image from a list Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I wanted to choose an image from a list of other images at random and blit them. This is an example of what i have so far.

```
Q1 = pygame.image.load("Math/Q1.jpg").convert()
math_list.append(Q1)
Q2 = pygame.image.load("Math/Q2.jpg").convert()
math_list.append(Q2)
Q3 = pygame.image.load("Math/Q3.jpg").convert()
math_list.append(Q3)
Q4 = pygame.image.load("Math/Q4.jpg").convert()
math_list.append(Q4)
Q5 = pygame.image.load("Math/Q5.jpg").convert()
math_list.append(Q5)
```

These are the variables i have appended to the list `math_list`. How would i now randomly choose one image, blit it at the coordinates (`200, 0`) and then make sure i dont open that image up again.
This is not the same as any others because it does not focus on pictures exactly. And does not show how to remove after iterating over them
Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: @Jongware it is not a duplicate as i have edited and explain :)

Comment: What you do with your list data is totally irrelevant - and so is the tag `pygame`. The question is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must first `import random`. To choose your image, do `image = math_list.pop(random.randint(0,len(math_list)-1))`. `randint` is used to choose a random number from 0 to 4, each one corresponding to an item in the list. `pop` removes that item and returns it to `image`.

Comment: When doing that i get the following error `image = math_list.pop(random.randint(0,4))
IndexError: pop index out of range` @pydude

Comment: @AhsenRauf see my edit.

Comment: the code iterates and blits every single image in the list unitl it is finished and then gives an error.

Comment: @AhsenRauf use `if len(math_list)>1: ` right before the random image chooser, and indent that line.

Comment: It fixes the error problem but i only want a single image to show up at a time. At the moment it blits every single image continuosly until it is done @pydude

Comment: @AhsenRauf i have solved your problem. If you want them one at a time you should post another question. Accept my answer (check mark under voting arrows) if it has helped you with your problem.

Comment: Alright dude. Your help is greatly appreciated :) @pydude

Comment: @AhsenRauf: you get an error when the list is empty. That is entirely consistent with your request ".. then make sure i dont open that image up again".